# Stopping flex items from pushing out other elements

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to create a sidebar. On the sidebar I would have multiple menu items and I also want a footer and "favorites" section. I want the footer to be at the bottom of the sidebar and I want to be able to have the favorites scroll-able if there are too much, but I just can't achieve this behavior.

Here is the base layout

```
<div className="w-full h-screen flex flex-row flex-nowrap p-6">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="w-full h-full px-4 flex items-center justify-center bg-slate-500">
        Other content
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the sidebar:

```
<div className="w-fit h-full bg-gray-800 rounded-xl text-gray-100 p-4 flex flex-col">
      <h1 className="text-2xl">Sidebar</h1>
      <div className="w-full h-full bg-red-400 flex flex-col justify-between">
        <div className="w-full h-fit px-2 flex flex-col gap-y-4">
          <div className="bg-gray-500">menu item 1</div>
          <div className="bg-gray-500">menu item 2</div>
          <div className="bg-gray-500">menu item 3</div>
          <div className="bg-gray-500">menu item 4</div>
          <div className="bg-gray-500">menu item 5</div>
          <div className="bg-gray-500">menu item 6</div>
          <hr />
          <div className="w-full h-fit flex flex-col bg-orange-800 gap-y-6">
            <div className="text-lg py-4">Favorite 1</div>
            <div className="text-lg py-4">Favorite 2</div>
            <div className="text-lg py-4">Favorite 3</div>
            <div className="text-lg py-4">Favorite 4</div>
            {/* if there are more here the elements push the footer out of the parent div */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full h-fit text-center text-blue-700 bg-purple-400 font-bold">
          Footer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I tried:
-I tried "overflow-y-scroll" on multiple parent elements and also tried adding max-h-? values to parent divs but none of these worked.

How it looks like currently:
[favorites should be scroll-able](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvabA.png)

The padding's are for representational purposes.

Comment: use `overflow-y-auto h-full` on favorites div

Comment: I tried that, the favorites div still pushes out the footer. I also tried setting max-h-screen and max-h-full on the parent divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a static height for the parent of the elements (favorites), then, set the overflow to auto:

`h-40 overflow-auto`